# Creating favourites list - how to copy item from one list to another on click?

Tags: javascript

(New to Javascript)

I have created a input box which turns the input value into a list item, and adds a star

I am trying to create a new list whereby when the star is clicked on, it will copy into the 'favourites' section

I have tried this, but it is not working

```
     let newStarSpan = document.querySelector("span")
        newStarSpan.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                //on click, get the parent node of the item clicked on 
                //i.e., want to return the individual <li> list item for the starSpan that was cliked on
                let favNode = this.parentNode 
                //create a copy of this list item (the parent node)
                let nodeCopy = favNode.cloneNode(true)
                //add it to list B - favourites list 
                listB.appendChild(nodeCopy)
```

https://codepen.io/jemimacholzer/pen/dyYMKxj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few issues in your code, the first issue is related to the selector

```
const listB = document.querySelector('listB')
```

update it with

```
Fix:
const listB = document.getElementById('listB')
```

the other issue is related to `newSpan` event declaration & its scope, the `newSpan` can't be accessed outside of `btn.onclick` function.

You also assigned click listener to `newSpan` which seems to declare & bind on page when no newSpan is present in Dom. So instead of defining the listener you need create a function which triggers on `newSpan` click and bind that function during `newSpan` creation.

```
const listA = document.getElementById("listA")
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const listB = document.getElementById('listB')

btn.onclick = function() {
        let Shopitem = input.value //store current value of input element in variable 
            input.value = ' ' //empty input element 

            const listItem = document.createElement('li') //creating a list item for the shopping item 
            listItem.setAttribute('id', Shopitem)
            const span = document.createElement('span') //list text 
            const newBtn = document.createElement('button') //creating button to delete item 
            var starSpan = document.createElement("span")
            var text = document.createTextNode("\u2B50")
            starSpan.appendChild(text)

            //making span and button children of the list item (containing within each list item)
            listItem.appendChild(starSpan)
            listItem.appendChild(span)  //add list text to list item 
            listItem.appendChild(newBtn) //add list remove button to list item 

            newBtn.textContent = 'Delete'
            span.textContent = Shopitem 

            listA.appendChild(listItem) //add li to the ul list 

            newBtn.onclick = function(e) {
                list.removeChild(listItem)
            }
          starSpan.onclick = function(e) {
                cloneListItem(listItem)
            }

            input.focus(); //focus the input method ready for entering the next shopping list item 
        }

        //need to create new reference to star span as old reference is inside eother function
        function cloneListItem(favNode){
                //create a copy of this list item (the parent node)
                let nodeCopy = favNode.cloneNode(true)
                //add it to list B - favourites list 
                listB.appendChild(nodeCopy)
        }
```

https://codepen.io/jemimacholzer/pen/dyYMKxj